# Python socket server, is there a way for user to input the port on terminal?

Tags: python, sockets, terminal

I have an assignment that wants me to create a socket program that have to user input the port number on terminal. So instead of the port being defined in the program, the port should be defined by: 
$ python3 socket_program.py < port_number > &

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The word "input" is already a good hint (at least for Python 3.x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use sys to access arguments passed into your script. Here's an example of taking the first argument passed into your script and assigning it to a variable called port.

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
  port = 3000
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, it needed me to convert it to str then int. "port = int(str(sys.argv[1]))"